# SELECT WHERE en MongoDB y C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Tengo una duda sobre MongoDB y C#, necesito filtrar las búsquedas por nombre de un empleado, es decir, colocas tu nombre en una caja de texto y si existe se muestran los datos en un `DataGrid`.

Estos son mis avances:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apepat { get; set; }
    public string apemat { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("base_datos");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("empleados");
    BindingList<Entity> doclist = new BindingList<Entity>();
    foreach (var deger in collection.Find("nombre", textBox1.Text))
    {
        doclist.Add(deger);
        string[] row0 = new string[] { deger.Id.ToString() };
        string[] row2 = new string[] { deger.nombre.ToString() };
        string[] row3 = new string[] { deger.apepat.ToString() };
        string[] row4 = new string[] { deger.apemat.ToString() };
        Application.DoEvents();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = doclist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta fue la manera en que resolví mi problema:

Con la Nueva version del controlador:

```
protected static IMongoClient cliente = new MongoClient();
protected static IMongoDatabase dataLocal = cliente.GetDatabase("base");
```

> En esta parte ya no es necesario definir la clase de ´tutabla´

```
var collection= dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tutabla");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", ab);
```

> Filter es el equivalente a where en las bases SQL, donde ab es el elemento a buscar en el campo _id de tu collection tutabla

Datos tiene en un listado todos los registros que cumplan la condición del ciclo

```
var datos= collection.Find<BsonDocument(filter).SetLimit(1).ToList();
```

En esta parte podemos hacer ´Counts´ , saltos o limites como es ´SQL´

```
var datos= collection.Find<BsonDocument(filter).Skip(0).Limit(10).ToList();
```

Por ultimo para resolver la Pregunta:

```
 foreach (var item in datos)
  {
   //dataGrid Add(name);
  }
```

O mediante la Segunda Forma:

```
   void cargargrilla()
    {          
        var conn = "mongodb://localhost";
        var client = new MongoClient(conn );
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("db");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<Empleados>("empleados");
        BindingList<Empleados> doclist = new BindingList<Empleados>();
        var query = Query.EQ("_id", idporfiltrar);
        var datos= collection .FindAs<BsonDocument (query).SetLimit(1).ToList();
        foreach (var deger in datos())
        {
            doclist.Add(deger);

            string[] row1 = new string[] { deger.nombre.ToString() };
            string[] row2 = new string[] { deger.descripcion.ToString() };
            string[] row3 = new string[] { deger.localidad.ToString() };
            Application.DoEvents();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = doclist;
        }

        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "IDD";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "ide";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Nombre";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Descripcion";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "descripcion";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Localidad";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "localidad";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de GetCollection, este devuelve un MongoCollection, en el que correctamente llamas a su función Find, pero esta función según la [documentación](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_1_Find.htm) recibe un parámetro *IMongoQuery*, que puedes crear usando [QueryBuilder](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_QueryBuilder_1.htm)

Comment: Tengo errores en el filtrado..

Comment: var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", "Rasralovely");

Comment: Intenta usar `var filtro = new QueryBuilder

Comment: `var filtro = new QueryBuilder<BsonDocument>().EQ<String>(/*expresion*/, textBox1.Text);`. La expresión se documenta aqui http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_QueryBuilder_1_EQ__1.htm pero estoy corto de tiempo ahorita